# django-registration in my Project Folder

Tags: django, django-registration

I have not tested it yet. But I hear when I install Django-registration, it is installed on your python path, not in the project it self. Is there any way, I can install as an APP under my project folder, so I will have more control over it?

If the answer is NO, is there a reason that I can't use separate packages under my projects?

Thanks,
RM

Answer (score 1):

You can do that of course. Just extract [the source package](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/registration) into your Django project folder. In the end your project direcotry should look like this:

```
my_project
    my_app
    registration
```

`registration` is the directory containing all the files from the link above. Don't forget to add `registration` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

One note: This is not good practice though. Even you would just install django-registration into your `PYTHONPAYH` there are still ways to extend it properly. It depends of course on the amount of modifications you want to make. Sometimes its enough to just overwrite a file like forms.py, urls.py or views.py. Put them into a custom registration application in your project, add them to `INSTALLED_APPS` **before** the main registration app and modifiy your project's `urls.py` so it will point to the views/urls/forms of your customized registration app.

All this requires though that you understand in detail how django-registration works.